# Accessing an NFS share from a Windows service

Tags: c#, .net, unix, nfs

- I have a Windows service that can't access an `NFS share` on a `UNIX` box. I can't access the share with the UNC path, so I have to have it mounted.
- I have a console application that can see the drive and runs fine, but when I deploy my Windows service, it can't see the drive.
- I have the drive mounted as my local user as well as the administrator.
- I've tried mounting a drive from my application by using `"Process.Start(mBatchFilePath);"`, but that didn't work either.
- I'm running as the local user (set as administrator).
- Tried using a symbolic link
- Going to try to set up an FTP to transfer the files

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this work?

**SOLVED:** I used SSH.Net and transfer files with an SFTP server

Comment: Interact with desktop is ticked?

Comment: Just to clarify, you installed the service *to run* under the administrator account? So that it really should be able to see the administrator's drives?

Comment: @Mike Miller -Interact with desktop is ticked.

Comment: @criticalfix - Sorry, that's confusing. I actually just installed the service. I didn't set it to run as admin because our IT guy didn't think it was a good idea. I'll take that part out of my question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that mapping the drive to a symbolic link is a real solution. The Problem is, that the service runs under a certain user account and thus it accesses all resources with the privileges of this account. Of course your IT admin is right, it's not a good idea to let the service run under the local administrator account.

You should create a new user account that is allowed to access the shared folder. Then set up the service that it runs under this account and the service should be able to access the network share. But remember, a network share that is mapped to a drive letter is only mapped for the current user. So the service (that runs under a different user account) simply doesn't have any drive with this letter, it is not mapped under its account.
So in your service you should always access the share with its full UNC path and not with a mapped drive letter.

Comment: I agree. The symbolic link turned out to not be a solution after all. I mentioned to IT that I'd like to access it with the UNC path, but they said it couldn't be done between Windows and our Solaris box. I don't really have any experience with UNIX so I have to take his word on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since we were connecting to a Solaris server from a windows box I needed to use SFTP to send files to the server.

I contemplated some sort of a folder sync, but it wasn't a route I wanted to go down.

I used the SSH.Net libraries.